# Can't get aptX codec to work in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, gstreamer, bluetooth-speaker, pipewire

I recently installed ubuntu 22.04. I have been trying to get aptX codecs to work for my bluetooth earbuds (momentum wireless 2), but they do not show up in the list of codecs. I have tried installing pipewire, but that didn't help either. My current pulseaudio version is 15.99. Before installing pipewire, gstreamer version was 1.20 and pulseaudio was 15.99.

On running "pactl send-message /card/bluez_card.XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX/bluez list-codecs" in the terminal, I get the available codecs to be SBC and SBC-XQ. Before installing pipewire, they were mSBC and a2dp. Any help in enabling aptx is appreciated.